# Reloading a url in JAVA

Tags: java, string, url, bufferedreader

```
public class ReadIp{
String nextLine;

public int getIP() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
         try
         {
        URL url = null;
        URLConnection urlConn = null;
        InputStreamReader inStream = null;
        BufferedReader buff = null;


        url = new URL("http://test.myrywebsite.co.uk/");
        urlConn = url.openConnection();
        inStream = new InputStreamReader(
                urlConn.getInputStream());
        buff = new BufferedReader(inStream);


        while ((nextLine = buff.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(nextLine);
        }}
         catch(Exception ex)
         {}
        return 0;

    }

     public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        ReadIp rp = new ReadIp();
        rp.getIP();
    }
}
```

I have this code above to extract information from the specified website. 
I have a website where it shows a sentence. Every time I reload the webpage, it will show a different sentence.

At the moment, with the code above, I need to manually run the program to show different sentences. Is there way where the program automatically reloads by itself? Do I use TimerTask?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{ 
    ReadIp rp=new ReadIp();
    while(true)
    {
        rp.getIp();
        Thread.sleep(1000); // sleep 1 second
    }
}
```

This will run forever or untill you kill the process.

Remark:
  also integrate inStream.close() somewhere to liberate resources.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. That helped. I understand it now.
There one more question I would like to ask.
Let's say I want to record the output sentence and give the recorded sentence its own ID, how would I proceed with it? Do I create a new array of strings each time for a new sentence and set id to the array and do it for every sentence? 

I have done it with a fixed list of words, and I assigned some sort of id to each word. I'm not sure when it comes to this since a new sentence appears randomly each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    ReadIp rp = new ReadIp();
    while (true)
    {
        rp.getIP();
        //wait 4 seconds
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. Specify what is different and how to solve the question.